# How to make swipe gesture from down to up to show a inner layout in java?

Tags: java, android, swipe, bottomnavigationview, swipe-gesture

I found a better file management app named as MT Manager. But there is a feature I like most you can see the GIF. Here if we swipe from Bottom Navigation Menu then you can see a beautiful custom layout coming up. If we see some Vivo Device this type gesture we found normally when we open the settings menu. So if anyone knows about it, then kindly please help me. I want to implement it on my app. You can check the below picture how the swipe gesture working.

[image: Like this]